# Having trouble with Peaks code Java. After compiling and running the program nothing is returned, what is the problem?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing code to find the peaks in a given array of integers.I can compile the code but when I run it nothing is returned despite me trying to print the list data2 and the integer total.

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class peaks1{

      public static void main(String[] args){
         }
      public static int main(int[] data){
         int peaks = -3;
         int[] data1 = {1,2,3,4,3,4,2,5};
         List<Integer> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
         int total = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i <= data1.length; i++){ 
            if (((data1[i] > data1[i+1]) && (i <= 0)))
                total += 1;
                data2.add(data1[i]);
            if ((data1[i] > data1[i+1]) && (data1[i] > data1[i-1])&&(i != 0))
                total += 1;
                data2.add(data1[i]);
                } 
            System.out.println(data2);
            System.out.println(total);
           return peaks;}
}
```

I am new to java and am wondering if I have made an oversight or if my core understanding is flawed? Anything helps!

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args)` is empty, so your program will literally do nothing.  Making other static methods and naming them "main" won't automatically run them.

Comment: Once you get that fixed, you should know that you need to put curly braces around multiple lines of code if you want them to execute in an `if` statement. Like: `if (((data1[i] > data1[i+1]) && (i <= 0))) {
                total += 1;
                data2.add(data1[i]); }`